# Vue array, get full array works, specific item in array is undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, axios

I am not sure how this is working in vue, So let me explain the scenerio.

I have a Vue component that does a call for 'groups' with axios on create. When I console.log() the response it is filled with the data. An array with objects.

```
data = response.data.data;
```

example console.log(data):

```
[__ob__: Observer]
0: {__ob__: Observer}
1: {__ob__: Observer}
2: {__ob__: Observer}
3: {__ob__: Observer}
4: {__ob__: Observer}
5: {__ob__: Observer}
6: {__ob__: Observer}
7: {__ob__: Observer}
8: {__ob__: Observer}
9: {__ob__: Observer}
10: {__ob__: Observer}
```

But if I do a console log after this one like so:

```
console.log(data);    <- this one filled with all the data.
console.log(data[0]); <- this one is 'undefined'
```

So why is the first item undefined even tho am pretty sure the array is filled because of the console.log() before that.

Anyone?

Comment: `console.log()` is asynchronous. The first log you see can be filled after your second one.

Comment: Try to console.log(response.data.data[0]);

Comment: @Zenoo that may be true, but its the same data, only more specific. So the data exists

Comment: @AdamOrlov it is done in a higher component, it is past via a prop

Comment: @NielsLucas I'm not denying it exists, I'm saying it could be filled afterwards. Try dropping a `debugger` right after your first log.

Comment: Could you set up a working example where this issue is reproducable?

Comment: @Sirence I will try today, Sorry about late reponse, was a bit buzy yesterday!